# Get an additional analog pin?

Tags: analogread, input, nodemcu

I have the following board:

[image]

As far as I can tell, there's only a single analog pin (`A0`). But I need at least 2 additional (for 3 total).

Is there some way to fake analog input on GPIO pins?

Comment: No. Get a SPI ADC.

Comment: What do you need to connect to the analog pins?  You can "bitbang" an ADC with some additional components, but it isn't trivial to do. Better go with an external ADC or use a different sensor that has a digital output instead of analog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ESP8266 only has one ADC pin. You can:

1. Use an analog MUX to switch that pin between different signals
2. Connect an external I2C ADC chip
3. Connect an external SPI ADC chip
4. Connect the ESP8266 to another MCU (such as an Arduino) and get that to do analog readings.